# How do I add System Monitor applet to the Gnome panel in Netbook Edition?

Tags: 10.10, ubuntu-netbook, gnome-panel, applet, system-monitor

I need to add the System Monitor applet to the Gnome Panel in Ubuntu Netbook Edition. My setup is as following: 10.10 (upgraded from 10.04) with Netbook Edition interface installed instead of Unity.

I've tried the method of symlinking Netbook Edition interface so that it would start in the Gnome session mode but the panel was not customizable anyway. Seems that the panel is more locked in 10.10 than in 10.04.

I suppose that the panel still keeps its applet configuration somewhere, either in config files or in gnome-config. So I think that it's possible to add an applet by editing the config. Does anybody know of files, commands and configuration keys that should be changed to add an applet? Or can I launch an applet by just running the program that renders it?

Answer (score 2):

There is a script (`/usr/lib/gnome-panel/gnome-panel-add`)
for adding applets and launchers to gnome-panel:

```
john@doe:~$ /usr/lib/gnome-panel/gnome-panel-add -h

Usage: gnome-panel-add [options]

Options:  
  -h, --help           show this help message and exit  
  --applet=APPLET      Applet to add  
  --copy-launcher      Copy the launcher to the user directory  
  --launcher=LAUNCHER  Launcher to add  
  --panel=TOPLEVEL     Identifier of the panel where to add the applet  
  --position=POSITION  Position on the panel where to add the applet  
  --right-stick        Make the applet right-aligned on the panel
```

The following command will add the *System Monitor* applet to the top panel, 500px from the left side of the screen:

```
/usr/lib/gnome-panel/gnome-panel-add --applet=OAFIID:GNOME_MultiLoadApplet --panel=top_panel_screen0 --position=500
```

**Note**: If you get a `top_panel_screen0 is not an existing panel identifier` error, replace  `top_panel_screen0` with one of the panel identifiers listed by the command:

```
gconftool --all-dirs /apps/panel/toplevels
```

Comment: Thanks for the first nail-on-the-head answer I've seen. But, well, I'm getting the following message: `glib.GError: Can't overwrite existing read-only value: Can't overwrite existing read-only value: Value for '/apps/panel/general/applet_id_list' set in a read-only source at the front of your configuration path`. And in the gconf-editor I can see that the key is, indeed, write-only but couldn't find any way to unlock it.

Comment: Oops, I meant read-only, write-protected.